# How to define the color of strokes

Tags: javascript, d3.js

In this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cad2m2ue/) how can I change the color of strokes?

I tried this code, but it does not change the color:

```
var colors = ["#F0E5FF","#E1CCFF","#C499FF","#AC79F2","#8D4CE5","#6100E5","#C94D8C"];

var colorScaleDomain = [100, 300, 1000, 10000, 50000, 600000];

var colorScale = d3.scale.threshold()
  .domain(colorScaleDomain)
  .range(colors);

link.style("stroke", function(d){
    return colorScale(d[0].size)
});
```

What is wrong in my code?

Comment: A fiddle with your code: https://jsfiddle.net/mkaran/om8tqotp/ with a slightly different color scale domain and a variation using  d3.scale.ordinal()  https://jsfiddle.net/mkaran/6qvjep7r/. I believe that the color scale domain you are giving is too wide, so the d[0].size falls into one category, thus it only gives one color. Try adjusting the domain better, e.g.: [300, 500, 1000, 1300, 1800, 2000, 5000, 10000, 13000, 18000, 20000] https://jsfiddle.net/mkaran/gLvnm0pf/

Comment: @mkaran: yes, that's because my real data set is much larger. Could you post an answer?

Comment: @mkaran: I slightly misunadestand one thing. If `var colors = ["#9EDAE5","#6100E5","#C94D8C"];` and `var colorScaleDomain = [300, 1000,20000]`, then all entries having `size` smaller than `300` will have the color `#9EDAE5`, right?

Comment: I believe this is correct. (https://github.com/d3/d3-scale/blob/master/README.md#threshold-scales)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, the problem lies in how the colorScaleDomain is chosen regarding your data "size" attribute. The way it is now, many values fall into one category, so one color is chosen. I'll try to provide a general solution, not a hardcoded scale:
https://jsfiddle.net/mkaran/3adu1u2n/
, where the colorScaleDomain is calculated by creating as many equal bins as the length of your colors

```
var colors = ["#F0E5FF","#E1CCFF","#C499FF","#AC79F2","#8D4CE5","#6100E5","#C94D8C"];
var maxSize = d3.max(classes, function(d) { return +d.size;} );
var colorScaleDomain = [];
var bin = Math.round(maxSize/colors.length);
for(let i=0; i < colors.length; i++){
  colorScaleDomain.push(bin*i)
}
console.log(colorScaleDomain)
var colorScale = d3.scale.threshold()
  .domain(colorScaleDomain)
  .range(colors);
```

example of scale: `[0, 3513, 7026, 10539, 14052, 17565, 21078]`

If you want to group the colors differently, you could try using a different variable than size. E.g. `d.imports.length` which will group them differently (https://jsfiddle.net/mkaran/snec9kgf/) and so on.

Comment: Maybe this will make it a bit more clear https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Quantitative-Scales.md#threshold `the default threshold scale is equivalent to the round function for numbers; for example threshold(0.49) returns 0, and threshold(0.51) returns 1.` So, similarly, the 1830 falls in the range of 1800-2000 which in turn is encoded to "#000000".

Comment: The function called is the following ` scale(x) {
      if (x <= x) return range[d3.bisect(domain, x)];
    }` and if the case is that colors.lenght is greater than colorScaleDomain, values such as 12000, 15000 etc will return `undefined`. Take a look at the console: https://jsfiddle.net/mkaran/2oq1hLys/

Comment: https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Quantitative-Scales.md#threshold_domain `If the number of values in the scale's range is N + 1, the number of values in the scale's domain must be N. If there are fewer than N elements in the domain, the additional values in the range are ignored. If there are more than N elements in the domain, the scale may return undefined for some inputs`